# Why is my input submit icon placed to the left of the input text box?

Tags: css, google-custom-search

I am trying to understand what's going on with my Google Custom Search Engine in the sidebar on the left here: http://bit.ly/1bmsJsi

I want the icon with the magnifying glass on the right of the text box instead of on the left. As far as I can tell looking at the code and my CSS, that's what ought to happen.

If someone can help me figure out why it goes on the left I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Put the item floating left BEFORE the item it's floating left beside (currently it's after it).

Comment: Thank you for replying! I tried changing the order around as you said (refresh to see), but the icon is still on the left. :/ I'm usually able to float elements just fine, I do it a lot elsewhere on the site, but this one has me stumped! Can you send me the lines of code you would use?

Comment: Oops, I totally read your wording wrong and I thought you wanted it on the left! When I previewed your page, it was already on the right! I'll go back and take a second look.

Comment: Wait, you saw it on the right when you previewed it? That's strange - I see it on the left (and did so even before I changed the ordering the two inputs, as you suggested).

Comment: Yeah, my monitor is giant, so that may have something to do with it. Floats are weird as they can have unexpected behaviour depending on how much room they have to work with. Moving it back to below the input and perhaps setting it's display to inline may help.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that; I'll have to check out how my site looks on a giant monitor since I use floats plenty! -- I did as you said, but unfortunately I still see the search icon on the left. :( (And you see it on the right again now?)

Comment: Thanks for looking at it; I appreciate it!